# finish a controller treatment before execute another

Tags: angularjs, controller

i have 2 controller loaded in one page : one loaded by $routeProvider,

application.js

```
.when('/service/:serviceId/:serviceName/',
                        {
                            templateUrl : 'view/service/service.html',
                            controller : 'ServiceController'
                        })
```

the other loaded in the view

service.html

```
<div align="left">
        <table class="table-flag">
            <tr ng-controller="LanguageController">
                <td ng-repeat="language in listLanguage"
                    width="50">                 
                    <input type="image" ng-src="img/flags/{{language.code}}.jpg"width="30" height="20"></input> </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div>

            <br />
            <ul>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr
                            ng-repeat="detail in service.infoList">                             
                            <td><span ng-bind-html-unsafe="detail.label"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I retrieve some datas from a server using rest

ServiceController

```
Info.controller('ServiceController', function ServiceController(
        $scope, $http, $routeParams, manageDatas) {


    $scope.serviceId = $routeParams.serviceId;
    $scope.serviceName = $routeParams.serviceName ;


    var paramsService = {
        serviceId : $scope.serviceId,
        serviceName : $scope.serviceName 
    };

    $scope.loading = true;

    var response = $http({

        url : 'rest/service',
        params : paramsService,
        method : 'GET'
    });

    response.success(function(service) {
        $scope.service = service;
        $scope.loading = false;
        manageDatas.setArrayData($scope.service.languageList);  // service which allow to pass an array in LanguageController           

    });


});
```

LanguageController

```
LanguageController.controller('LanguageController', function ServiceByLanguageController(
        $scope, $http, $routeParams, $timeout , manageDatas , $route) {


    $scope.listLanguage = manageDatas.getDatas(); // retrieve the array passed in ServiceController by a service
   // always null

});
```

The problem is the $http.success method in ServiceController is always executed AFTER LanguageController(verified by breakpoints) so the array $scope.listLanguage is always empty because i don t pass datas....

How can i make the languageController be executed after all the treatments in serviceController finish ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can broadcast event in response.success(function(service) {...}, say, using $rootScope, and let LanguageController listen to this event and then do assignment $scope.listLanguage = ...

Answer (score 0):

Just after a brief look, I would say that part or all of your ServicesController logic should be in a service and not a controller. You seem to have such a service in manageDatas. Just put all the code that actually loads and writes data to the service inside the service.

Comment: Thanks , i will try this. So i need to put all my restful logic in a service and keep the variables in the controller right ?

Comment: Something like that yes.